# Blueimp File Upload with Browserify

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm trying to setup [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) using browserify.  I've tried the following to require it after installing via npm:

```
require('blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js');
require('blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js');
require('blueimp-file-upload/js/jquery.fileupload-process.js');
```

This however throws an error that 'jquery' is not found in the vendor directory - which it doesn't exist.

Would anyone know how to include this using browserify?

Comment: Ok, I was able to get it to recognize jquery by adding `global.jQuery = require("jquery");`, however now I get that `$(...).fileupload is not a function`, seems like it's not recognizing the plugin.